# How do I design a reward function given two parameters

Tags: statistics, functions

We want to design a reward function R(x, y) where $x \in [0, 1]$ and $y \in (0, 10000)$ such that x is the dominant term when its value is close to or equal to 1, whereas y is dominant when x is small.

The problem I'm trying to solve is that given pairs $(x_1, y_1), (x_2, y_2), ...$, I want to select the best pair. Ideally, the best pair should be one with x = 1, and y = 10000. We care about x more when it's very close to 1, and in this case y can be ignored. On the other hand, when x is not close to 1, we want to have a tradeoff between x and y.

Answer (score 0):

Try $x + (1-x)y$.  You can make it more complicated in many ways e.g. $x^a + D*(1-x)^b y^c$, but start simple.